# Generate C# classes with XMLSPy 2010rel3sp1

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I've used xsd.exe to generate c# classes several times.  I've had a few issues with this tool and wanted to compare the code generation from XMLSpy.  Can someone direct me on how to generate the C# classes with this tool?

Answer (score 2):

In Altova XMLSpy open your schema. On the DTD/Schema menu, there is an option "Generate Program Code". This pops open a window where you can select the language and options for generation. Select what you need for generation, click OK, choose the save location and you're good to go!

Cheers!

Comment: I thought that this should be a simple process, but I'm not seeing it on my 'DTD/Schema' menu.

Comment: I have 'Generate XML from DB, Excel, EDI with MapForce ...' and a 'Generate Sample XML File ...' with some other Convert, Assign, and Go To options.

Comment: This is probably a problem with the version you're using. Only the Enterprise version has the capability to generate code. The Professional and Standard versions of XMLSpy do not include this feature.